# Excluding Cells Without Numeral Values in a Range for an Increment Function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have this function where I want to Add one increment to every Numeral Value in the B Column. I have this currently which works but it also tags a one onto the end of each Instance of Age In my Sheet. This is the current function:

```
function AgeUp(){
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B6:B70");
  var cellValues = cell.getValues().map(function(row) {return [row[0] + 1]}); // Modified
  cell.setValues(cellValues); // Modified
  
}
```

And so basically I'd like to have it Add one to all in column B but only if they have a numerical value. How do I do this while also exclude those without numbers in them?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to add `1` when the value is the number.
- You don't want to add `1` when the value is NOT the number.

#### Modification point:

- In this case, I thought that `isNaN` can be used. This is used in the loop of `map`.

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var cellValues = cell.getValues().map(function(row) {return [row[0] + 1]});
```

To:

```
var cellValues = cell.getValues().map(function([v]) {return [isNaN(v) || v == "" ? v : Number(v) + 1]});
```

- In this modified script, when the value is not the number and the empty, `1` is not added.
- When you want to add `1` for the empty value, please modify as follows.

  ```
    var cellValues = cell.getValues().map(function([v]) {return [isNaN(v) ? v : Number(v) + 1]});
  ```

#### Reference:

- [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)